# Retrieve time spent between two iterations in C

Tags: c, multithreading, clock

I have threads running, the threaded function contains a loop and iterates for a certain amount of time.

Per exemple:

```
void *start(void *p) // This function is called at the thread creation
{
      int i = 0;

      while (i < 10){
          i++;
      }
} // NOTE THAT THIS FUNCTION IS AN EXAMPLE, the iteration can be small or high.
```

How may I monitor the time spent between two iterations? (Taking into consideration the fact that I have many threads running it at the same time)

I have heard of the `clock()` function, and the following operation to determine the time spent between two `clock()` outputs:

```
(double)(begin - end) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

How may I retrieve such information in an efficient manner?

Comment: You might like to RTFM here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html

Comment: Another option would be to use a profiler. Which one to use might depend on the platform the code is running on.

Comment: @alk: I have read it of course, but my question is mostly about efficiency and perhaps finding another way of achieving such results.

Comment: 1) Change 'while (i < 10)' to 'while (i < 100000000)'.  2) Buy a stopwatch.

Comment: Add another '0', and you can use a cooking timer.  I use a Salter 'BIGTIME' for my pizza and code timing.

Comment: You did make me laugh during class, thank you. Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the POSIX function [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime):

```
#include <time.h>

timespec real_startTime;
timespec real_endTime;      

// Start time measurement
if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &real_startTime) != 0)
{
    perror("Error on fetching the start-time");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Do some long running operation that should be measured

// Stop time measurement
if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &real_endTime) != 0)
{
    perror("Error on fetching the end-time");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

double real_runTime = (real_endTime.tv_sec + real_endTime.tv_nsec / 1000.0 / 1000.0 / 1000.0) - (real_startTime.tv_sec + real_startTime.tv_nsec / 1000.0 / 1000.0 / 1000.0);
```

The difference to clock is that this outputs the *wall-clock time*, the "real" time that passed executing something (including I/O, etc.), rather than [`clock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) which is based on *CPU time*.

Excerp clock_gettime man:

> All implementations support the system-wide realtime clock, which is identified by CLOCK_REALTIME. Its time represents seconds and nanoseconds since the Epoch.

Excerp clock man:

> The clock() function returns an approximation of processor time used
>          by the program.

---

EDIT:
As suggested by many, you will not encounter any real difference in your example code (counting an integer from 0 to 10), but you will if you measure some long running system, a system doing I/O, etc.).

Comment: I'm not convinced that such calls have the accuracy to time a CPU counting up to 10.

Comment: @MartinJames: You are right, I added a comment regarding that in my answer.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that `clock_gettime` is a POSIX function, not a C function. In standard C, I'm afraid you're stuck with `clock()` and `time()`.

Comment: How about using lttng?